# How To Convert Number format from Scientific Notation to Number python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

So in my csv file, a column of numbers are listed in scientific notation (Ex:1.945019e+11), but its not just zeroes past the 1.945019. There are more values, like 1.9450192304..., and its possible to revert the notation to a number in excel. How can I get python to convert this scientific notation back to a number?

Comment: pandas may be the easiest fix

Comment: Is excel simplifying the numbers? Or are the values themselves simplified?

Comment: im not sure, but i know in excel i can change the format of the numbers and the rest of the digits show up, so it may be simplifying.

Comment: What do you see if you use an ordinary text editor to open the CSV file? It is only possible to get information from data that is actually there.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I went on vacation lol. On notepad it does show up

Comment: its all good - they just show up in scientific notation in terminal but i think they dont need to be toucehd

Answer (score 0):

You can't invent digits that aren't there.  If the CSV contains 1.945019E+11, then that's all you can read.  You need to get Excel to save the extended format.

Excel stores in the CSV exactly what is displayed on the screen.  If you have the cell format set to 6 decimals, then that's all it is going to write in the CSV.  You'll have to expand the onscreen format to show what you want.

Perhaps you will need to read the xlsx file directly.